# Leading 0xff in C structure components in the output

Tags: c, struct

Something of the strangest nature is happening. Follows the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct s
{
  char a;
  char b;
  char c;

  unsigned int d;
  unsigned int e;
}__attribute__((packed));

int main(void)
{
  struct s *m = (void *)malloc(sizeof (struct s));
  assert(m);

  m->a=0x33;
  m->b=0x33;
  m->c=0x33;
  m->d=0xabcdefab;
  m->e=0x12345678;
  *(char *)(m + 1) = 0;

  while (*((char*)m))
  {
    printf("%p -> %x\n", m, *((char *)m));
    m = (struct s *)((char*) m + 1);
  }
}
```

And here is the output:

```
0x85a010 -> 33
0x85a011 -> 33
0x85a012 -> 33
0x85a013 -> ffffffab
0x85a014 -> ffffffef
0x85a015 -> ffffffcd
0x85a016 -> ffffffab
0x85a017 -> 78
0x85a018 -> 56
0x85a019 -> 34
0x85a01a -> 12
```

By now, you probably have spotted the bizareness in the output. Indeed, there are no '0xff' in memory at addresses 0x85a013 to 0x85a016, nor is there 4 bytes per byte?!?! (I mean, is that even logical ?). It seems to me that it is a display problem, but I cannot figure out why or how.

Comment: You're writing out of bound of allocated memory. `m + 1` is equal to doing e.g. `m[1]`. And writing out of bounds of allocated memory leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and makes your whole program ill-formed.

Comment: It happened to all the negative chars, not terribly surprising

Comment: More related to your question, types smaller than `int` are converted to `int` when passed as arguments to a variable-argument function like `printf`, that means your `char` values are converted (with *sign extension*) to `int`. And it's that *sign extension* that causes the `ff` to be printed. Try changing the format to `"%p -> %02x\n"` instead, that will print only two significant digits.

Comment: I fail to understand the point of all the casting, and can't follow the code because of it. Are you playing tricks? Why do you cast as `(void *)malloc()` when that is its return type?

Comment: @WeatherVane The OP could have made it easier to read using a variable such as e.g. `char *p = (char *) m;`, and using `p` instead of `m` and the casting, In other words, what the OP is doing is printing all the bytes of a structure one by one.

Comment: Oh god, this was so obvious, how could I miss it. Thank you.
Yes I know I am writing out of bounds, that was to be able to iterate on the value pointed by (char*)m until it was null.
Wasn't playing tricks, just playing around to get familiar with type casting, that is also why I did not use any intermediate variable to hold the typecast.
The (void *) cast was a mistake.

Comment: If I may ask one more thing (although unrelated): is it a good thing to check for malloc failure, or for any failure at all, with asserts ?
ie `char *s = malloc(10); assert(s);` or even `int r = open(...); assert(r >= 0);`

Comment: Yes, you *must* check for failure from *all* functions that return a pointer or status value. That is how you write **robust** code. It's more work writing, but pays back later.

Comment: No my question was to know if checking the returned values with the assert() macro was faulty. I used to check it this way and my teacher did not like it for some reason. I am not sure whether to trust him or not. I'd actually go for the latter.

Comment: @amaenaide: "...nor is there 4 bytes per byte" - what is that supposed to mean?

Comment: @amaenaide as long as your method is reliable. I don't use `assert`, I simply check what is returned. I abort in one of 3 ways, depending on the code complexity. 1) `printf()` and `exit()`, 2) a function `fatal(char *msg)` which reports the error, does any cleanup, and exits, or 3) a function `faterr()` which takes a variable number of arguments so as to work like `printf()`.

Comment: @WeatherVane I do 2), but assert() seems good when I am sure I want to exit the program without any notification.

AnT yes, since I was printing 1byte at a time, I was surprised to find 4 of them at those addresses. I didn't know what to think, thus the stupid comment.

Comment: And don't do all the casts, they only show that you don't master C's type system. The return of `malloc` **is** `void*`, so there really isn't any point. All your busy cast of `m` to access individual bytes is unreadable bloat. Just cast your `struct` pointer once to `unsigned char*`, and then iterate over that. The correct format to print an `unsigned char` then is `%hhx`.

Comment: @JensGustedt: "... is unreadable bloat" -  indeed this code sacrifices redability

Comment: @JensGustedt Maybe you have not read my comments. Plus, I never had any claims regarding the mastery of C.

Comment: @Vain, sorry no personal offence intended. What really worries me is that you must have seen such bad code somewhere, when you tried to learn C. There seem to be a lot of bad code examples out there, would be good if beginners would find the good ones more easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Change `(char *)` casts to `(unsigned char *)`. And to prevent undefined behaviour, don't try to post a sentinel, but work with the struct size. My version:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct s
{
    char a;
    char b;
    char c;
    unsigned int d;
    unsigned int e;
};
#pragma pack(pop)

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    unsigned char *cptr;
    struct s *m = malloc(sizeof (struct s));
    assert(m);

    m->a=0x33;
    m->b=0x33;
    m->c=0x33;
    m->d=0xabcdefab;
    m->e=0x12345678;

    cptr = (unsigned char*)m;
    for (i=0; i<sizeof(struct s); i++)
        printf("%p -> %02x\n", (void*)(cptr+i), cptr[i]);
}
```

Program output:

```
001C2DD0 -> 33
001C2DD1 -> 33
001C2DD2 -> 33
001C2DD3 -> ab
001C2DD4 -> ef
001C2DD5 -> cd
001C2DD6 -> ab
001C2DD7 -> 78
001C2DD8 -> 56
001C2DD9 -> 34
001C2DDA -> 12
```

Comment: `*(unsigned char *)(m + 1) = 0;` this is undefined behavior, no?

Comment: @AlejandroDíaz That's still UB.

Comment: Thank you for the answer as well. Additionnally, the use of #pragma thought me.

Comment: The correct format to print an `unsigned char` is `"%hhx"`.

Comment: @WeatherVane:to be on the safe side you should cast cptr[i] to unsigned inside printf

Comment: @Giorgi isn't `char` (and `unsigned char`) promoted anyway?

Comment: @Weather Vane: thing is unsigned char can be promoted ro int - but %x needs unsigned int i guess

Answer (score 1):

This is being caused by signed integer promotion. The `printf` specifier for %x wants at least a full sized `int` value.

And to avoid various problems with value sizes, variable argument functions like `printf` convert values into at least `int` and `double` sizes.

That means that a `signed char` value like 0xab is sign-extended to a 32-bit `0xffffffab`

Comment: I thought %x was expecting unsigned int

Comment: @Giorgi: %x doesn't really care. It's going to be output in hex anyway. The integer promotion comes during the function call, not during the value-to-text conversion.

Comment: I read somewhere it was expecting uint, http://trust-in-soft.com/printing-an-unsigned-char-with-x-or-u-is-not-absolutely-correct/

Answer (score 1):

Format specifier `%x` requires `unsigned int` argument in `printf`. Using an `int` argument in its place is only allowed if the `int` value is non-negative. If the value is negative, the behavior is undefined.

You are passing a `char` argument for `%x` format specifier. A variadic `char` argument gets automatically converted to `int` and passed as `int`. If the original `char` (and therefore the resultant `int`) happens to have a negative value, the behavior is undefined. This is apparently what happens in your case. Your `ff` output is a consequence of your invalid attempts to print negative `int` values by using `%x` format specifier.

You can fix your broken code in several different ways. For example, you can convert the `printf` argument to `unsigned int` type explicitly

```
printf("%p -> %x\n", (void *) m, (unsigned) *((char *)m));
```

This will get rid of the undefined behavior, but will most likely leave the output unchanged. Now the `ff` will appear as a [perfectly defined] consequence of modulo conversion of negative value to `unsigned int` type.

This

```
m = (struct s *)((char*) m + 1);
```

is also a formally questionable practice. The language does not guarantee you that a `struct` pointer can preserve the exact value of a `char *` pointer.

Comment: That looks like a great remark. I think of pointers as specifiers for structure sizes: to me, a pointer is an address, therefore isn't its length relative to the machine architecture ? and isn't the length of an address fixed ? The only difference I can see between a pointer to char, a pointer to int, a pointer to some structure or whatever is the size at which the dereferencing occurs. So how come the language does not guarantee a struct pointer preserves the value of a char pointer ? Again, aren't pointers all addresses (of fixed sizes)?

Comment: @amaenaide: The rationale here is rooted in alignment requirements. If some type `T` is aligned, say, on 4-byte boundary, the language (and the underlying machine platform) might not guarantee that the last two bits of `T *` pointers are preserved. The machine might require all pointers of type `T *` to have zeros in the last two bits. Trying to increment such `T *` pointer by 1 byte might end up having no effect because of this. Pointer `T *` would only be incrementable by 0, 4, 8, 16, 24... and so on bytes. Any other increment would "snap" to a nearest lesser value from the above sequence.

Comment: This is the reason the language explicitly states that round-trip pointer conversion `T * -> U * -> T *` is guaranteed to produce the original `T *` value if and only if the original `T *` pointer value is also properly aligned for `U *` type.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't think I understand. Maybe I would get it with an example if you got one. Ofc, I do understand I cannot increment an int pointer by 1, hoping to get the next byte out of it, but I believe it's not what you mean by this, is it not ? Do you actually mean I cannot cast a uint16 pointer into a -- say -- uint25 pointer, increment it and get away with it because uint16 pointers must be aligned on 2bytes boundaries while imaginary uint25 pointers should be hypotetically (well, not aligned) -- but that would still mess with the alignment of the uint16. Do I even make sense ?

Comment: @amaenaide: Yes, that's exactly what I mean. You can increment a `char *` pointer by 1 byte. But you are not guaranteed to be able to increment a `struct s *` pointer by 1 byte. Of course, it will typically work in practice, but the language makes no formal guarantee about it.

Comment: I understand the bother, it is about the standard. However, I cannot imagine a reason for which it would ever not work in practice. Unless... would I be right to assume that, unlike x86, some architectures might very well be unable to read memory chunks that would not fit memory alignment requirements ?